# Django ckeditor and django tables2 safe render

Tags: django, ckeditor4.x, django-tables2

I am using django tables2 https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2 to display data in a table in my template that has been created by django-ckeditor https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor. Specifically the issue I am having relates to the rendering in the table of a LinkColumn:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    notes = tables.LinkColumn('notes_update', kwargs={"pk": Accessor("pk")},attrs={'th': {'id': 'thnotes'}, 'td': {'id': 'tdnotes'}})
```

The data is displayed in the table with the html `<p> <p/>` tags, as created by ckeditor.

From what I can gather I need to render in the template using the `{{ |safe }}` tag in order to display the table data without html `<p> <p/>` tags with but im at a loss as to how to achieve this in conjunction with django tables2 as my table is rendered in my template as follows:

```
{% render_table table %}
```

I have tried without success to surround this with:

```
  {% autoescape off %}
  {% render_table table %}
  {% endautoescape %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to help me render `notes` data in my table without the html `<p> <p/>` tags? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is to use a [`tables.TemplateColumn`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn):

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    notes = tables.TemplateColumn(
        template_code='''<a href="{% url 'notes_update' pk=record.pk %}">{{ record.notes |safe }}</a>''',
        attrs={'th': {'id': 'thnotes'}, 'td': {'id': 'tdnotes'}}
    )
```

This should give you a familiar template to control the contents of your table cells.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thank you so much. It was just missing a closing double quotation mark between }> after pk=record.pk %}. Perhaps you can edit your answer for future visitors?

Comment: Thanks, added the missing quote.